# Getting a column from a data frame into another based on lookup values from 2 columns

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames as given below. I want to append the 4th column of DS2 in DS1 based on the look up value of column 2 and column 3.

DS1

```
Entity  Service Type    Service Description Unit Price Incurred Volume    Total Service Charge in USD 
Entity1 WIRE & OTHER FUNDS TRNSF SVCS   CPO GP CUST MNT TEMP STORAGE    0.15    1024    153.6
Entity1 PAYMENT TRANSACTIONS    WIRE-HVC-LOCAL PAYMENT STP DR SHA   5.62    459 2579.58
Entity1 PAYMENT TRANSACTIONS    WIRE-HVC-LOCAL PAYMENT STP DR OUR   8.27    88  727.76
Entity1 PAYMENT TRANSACTIONS    FOREIGN WIRE PAYMENT STP DR SHA 19  40  760
```

DS2

```
Entity  Service Type    Service Description Unit Price Agreed
Entity1 WIRE & OTHER FUNDS TRNSF SVCS   CPO GP CUST MNT TEMP STORAGE    0.15
Entity1 PAYMENT TRANSACTIONS    WIRE-HVC-LOCAL PAYMENT STP DR SHA   5.62
Entity1 PAYMENT TRANSACTIONS    WIRE-HVC-LOCAL PAYMENT STP DR OUR   8.27
Entity1 PAYMENT TRANSACTIONS    FOREIGN WIRE PAYMENT STP DR SHA 15
```

I tried `bcagd <- join(ctse1,bcagd, by = "Service Type")`but it is throwing an error unused argument. I have many line in the datasets. Please suggest the correct function to use.

Comment: Please format your `data.frame` so you can tell where one column stops and the next starts.  Even better, paste the output of `dput`

Comment: I tried using merge but the I want the output file with line items which were not found in the DF2 with an NA or some flag in the unit.price.agreed column. I am new to SO, so might go go bad in formatting the question. I used merge bcagd2 <- merge(bc2, bcagd, by = c("Entity","Service.Type", "Service.Description"))

Comment: Here the line items for which the match is not found are going missing

Comment: Look at the linked question to read the different type of joins. Or type `?merge` and read about `all`

Comment: You can use `left_join` i.e. `library(dplyr);left_join(DS1, DS2, by = names(DS1)[1:3])`

Comment: Thanks, thats very useful